# .PS1 only partially running from .BAT

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to run a PS1 from a BAT file, but it only runs parts of the PS1. The PS1 runs fine outside of the BAT file.

From the BAT: (This is the line in the BAT for this entry. The BAT gives me a prompt, I type "add tns" and it runs the PS1)

```
if "%web%"=="add tns" PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'H:\cheats\add_tns\add_tns.ps1'"
```

From the PS1: (This is the PS1, it gives some prompts I enter the information, it puts it into a TXT file then takes the contents of the TXT file and adds it to the ORA file)

```
$Connection = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input name of DB'
$Protocol = Read-Host -Prompt 'TCP or TCPS'
$Protocol = $Protocol.ToUpper()
$IP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input IP'
$Port = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Port'
$Service_Name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Service_Name'
$Service_Name = $Service_Name.ToUpper()

"$Connection =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = $Protocol)
               (HOST = $IP)
               (PORT = $Port)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = $Service_Name)
    )
  )
" > text.txt

$From = Get-Content -Path H:\cheats\add_tns\text.txt
Add-Content -Path C:\instantclient_12_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora -Value $From
```

What happens is it runs the prompts, I put in information, but it does not put it in the TXT file, then it takes whatever is already in the TXT and puts it in the ORA file. So it's skipping the middle section, the quoted section, of the PS1.

Comment: Does it work better if you change this ending bit `" > text.txt` to `" > H:\cheats\add_tns\text.txt`?

Comment: To add to @notjustme's comment: the `text.txt` file is created in whatever directory is the working directory from the batch file's perspective. Thus, the file probably _is_ being created, but not where you expect it to. Please clarify where you want the file to be created.

Comment: You should also be using `If /I "%web%"=="add tns" PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "H:\cheats\add_tns\add_tns.ps1"`, the greater emphasis on the use of `-File` over `-Command`.